# ''and draw a new card?'' Who should draw the new card? The person playing this card or the opponent he chooses?

Tags: love-letter

https://ibb.co/4FYFfqZ Picture is here. Question is simple. Who should draw the card?
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The player you chose to discard a card draws the new card. The idea is that every player always has exactly 1 card in their hand except during their turn when they draw a second before choosing one to play/discard.

While the language on the card could be ambiguous, the rulebook is clearer:

> When you discard Prince Arnaud, choose one player still in the round (including yourself). That player discards his or her hand (do not apply its effect) and draws a new card.

Note that in general, the wording on the cards acts as more of a summary; the rulebook contains the full details for each card.